# Not able to use canvas function in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi

I am beginning to learn GDI graphics in Delphi 7. I am having problems in drawing Ellipses , Text etc. on my Main form.  Basically I use this code:

```
     Form1.Canvas.TextOut(10,10,'sss');
```

Is this Canvas Property required to be associated with the Form? I haven't done any thing like that. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: What's your problem exactly? Where have you put that code? Try putting it in the `OnPaint` event if you haven't done so.

Comment: Problem is Solved. OnPaint did the trick. Please post it as an answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you put all painting code in the form's `OnPaint` event handler ([documentation](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Forms_TForm_OnPaint.html)). This handler is called whenever the form needs to be repainted.

```
procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
begin
Canvas.TextOut(10,10,'sss');
end;
```

Comment: +1 I didn't know that the form had an OnPaint, I've always used TPaintBox. Always more things to learn!!

Comment: @David: it is published, so in plain sight. <vbg>

Comment: @rudy I'm very happy to admit my knowledge is very incomplete and I always want to learn more. That's my main motivation for my SO activity. I would have thought that would be an admirable quality, not a cause for sniggering.

Comment: @David: no need to get upset. I merely made a joke. I am also here to learn. Everyone's knowledge is limited, mine too.

Comment: @David Yup, OnPaint is handy, but it's not holy. Using a PaintBox's canvas is much more robust then that of a Form. For when you have Delphi around again: f.i. [this program](http://www.nldelphi.com/Forum/showthread.php?p=301898#post301898) magically fails in drawing on a Form's canvas (hit _Functiegenerator_).