# Cant write to a form's canvas

Tags: delphi, canvas

I am creating a form on the fly and would like to draw on its canvas however I'm unable to do so.  No errors are generated just no output.

Here is the simple test code

```
procedure TForm11.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Fm: TForm;
  R: TRect;
begin
  try
    Fm := TForm.Create(nil);
    Fm.Position := poScreenCenter;
    Fm.Caption := 'Test';
    Fm.Width := 600;
    Fm.Height := 400;
    Fm.Color := clGreen;

    Fm.Canvas.Font.Color := clBlack;
    Fm.Canvas.Font.Size := 12;
    Fm.Canvas.Pen.Color := clBlack;
    Fm.Canvas.Pen.Width := 5;
    Fm.Canvas.Brush.Color := clRed;;
    Fm.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;

    R.Left := 10;
    R.Top := 10;
    R.Width := 100;
    R.Height := 100;

    Fm.Canvas.TextOut(200, 10, 'Hello');
    Fm.Canvas.Rectangle(R);

    Fm.ShowModal;
  finally
    Fm.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: [Not able to use canvas function in Delphi 7](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7147045/1699210)

Comment: WM_ERASEBKGRND looks like your guy

Answer (score 6):

The canvas is redrawn all the time when you click controls, move the form around. In your case you draw the image, but after that, the form is shown and it will (re)-draw itself, overwriting your drawing. In order to keep your drawing, you could draw it in the `OnPaint` event of the form, which is invoked everytime the form needs to repaint itself.

```
procedure TForm11.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Fm: TForm;
begin
  Fm := TForm.Create(nil);
  try
    Fm.Position := poScreenCenter;
    Fm.Caption := 'Test';
    Fm.Width := 600;
    Fm.Height := 400;
    Fm.Color := clGreen;
    Fm.OnPaint := MyFormPaint;

    Fm.ShowModal;
  finally
    Fm.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm11.MyFormPaint(Sender: TObject);
var
  Fm: TForm;
  R: TRect;
begin
  FM := TForm(Sender);

  Fm.Canvas.Font.Color := clBlack;
  Fm.Canvas.Font.Size := 12;
  Fm.Canvas.Pen.Color := clBlack;
  Fm.Canvas.Pen.Width := 5;
  Fm.Canvas.Brush.Color := clRed;;
  Fm.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;

  R.Left := 10;
  R.Top := 10;
  R.Width := 100;
  R.Height := 100;

  Fm.Canvas.TextOut(200, 10, 'Hello');
  Fm.Canvas.Rectangle(R);
end;
```

Another solution would be to draw it on the canvas of a Bitmap, assign that bitmap to a TImage's Picture property, and show the TImage on the form. Then, everytime when the form needs to repaint, it lets each control repaint itself too, and the image will redraw the bitmap, so it remains visible.

```
procedure TForm11.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Fm: TForm;
  Img: TImage;
  B: TBitmap;
  R: TRect;
begin
  Fm := TForm.Create(nil);
  try
    Fm.Position := poScreenCenter;
    Fm.Caption := 'Test';
    Fm.Width := 600;
    Fm.Height := 400;

    // Add an image. Make the form the owner. That way, it is automatically 
    // discarded when you free the form in the `finally` block.
    Img := TImage.Create(Fm);

    // Make the form the parent too, and make sure the image covers the form.
    Img.Parent := Fm;
    Img.Align := alClient;

    // Get bitmap of the picture. This will automatically create
    // a bitmap for it too, which is managed by the image.
    // You just have to give it the right dimensions.
    B := Img.Picture.Bitmap;
    B.Width := Fm.ClientWidth;
    B.Height := Fm.ClientHeight;

    // The image is not transparent, so you'll have to draw the green background too.
    B.Canvas.Brush.Color := clGreen;
    B.Canvas.FillRect(B.Canvas.ClipRect);

    // Draw on the canvas of the bitmap.
    B.Canvas.Font.Color := clBlack;
    B.Canvas.Font.Size := 12;
    B.Canvas.Pen.Color := clBlack;
    B.Canvas.Pen.Width := 5;
    B.Canvas.Brush.Color := clRed;;
    B.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;

    R.Left := 10;
    R.Top := 10;
    R.Width := 100;
    R.Height := 100;

    B.Canvas.TextOut(200, 10, 'Hello');
    B.Canvas.Rectangle(R);

    Fm.ShowModal;
  finally
    Fm.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Golez Trol - Thanks for your answers, the second is my preference.  I had already started to go down that route but hadn't set the bitmap width and height correctly so nothing displayed.

Comment: You're welcome. I forgot that too at first when I made this example, but fortunately I bumped into that issue before and remembered how to solve it. It's good to remember that TImage is just a way to display a picture, and the size of the image/picture/bitmap is not automatically scaled to the image itself.

Comment: @EssexPAL Don't you think this answer should have been accepted? (Read more here: [What should I do when someone answers my question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) )